# How to handle game states for a single-player / multiplayer game?

Tags: architecture, software-engineering

I'm developing a little simon-like game and I'd like to know what the best approach is when it comes down to game states.

What would be the best approach?

- Creating different states/screens for 1-player and 2-player game sessions.
- Creating just one state/screen with validation from a variable that holds the selection made by the player on the title screen.

Comment: Is the single player the same game but against the computer or does the actual game differ?

Comment: I viewed this question just to find out what a "one half player game" is.  I'm still wondering.

Comment: Well, it was intended to be 1 or 2. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want your 1 player and 2 player game to be the same class with a 1/2 player toggle. Otherwise your code base is going to be unnecessarily forked.

Comment: He could inherit the same objects for both states, I guess.

Comment: @zarawesome if he did inherit both from a base class he might well find himself adding functionality in one subclass that he later needs in the other, leading to lots of refactoring.

Answer (score 5):

Generally the game is only "multiplayer" when the game is in the actual gameplay mode--ie state 3. It is fairly common to just allow one player to "drive" in all other states. This is why you are often asked to "Press [button] to continue": to determine which controller/player is "driving". Then, when the main gameplay state is reached, the screen is split based on how many controller or players are actually connected.

Comment: In addition, this is one reason it's very common to have an intermediate "choose your profile" (or sometimes "choose your character") screen - so the game can figure out which controllers are "live" and which are merely connected but unused.